# SVN verify doesn't detect corrupted revision

Tags: bash, svn, subgit

Trying to identify any corrupted revisions prior to a subgit conversion.

This is a bit backwards. I know there is corruption, however:

```
svnadmin verify [repo]
```

Insists that all the revisions are OK.
For example, I know that `rev 10979` is corrupted, as when using the webadmin tool, all the files are not viewable.

I've `dumped and loaded` the repo to another server, and the corrupted rev transfers happily, but causes issues during conversion.

Comment: If SubGit seemed to hang translating this revision, it might be caused by the very changes introduced by that revision -- if, for example, the svn project layout had been changed significantly. Most probably it can be resolved by correcting the mapping configuration, but it will definitely require manual intervention.

Comment: I've checked it out on WebSVN at that revision, it appears that the content is actually corrupted. I can't checkout the rev, or view the contents of the file (it's garbage) so why would SVN not consider that it's corrupted?